# Step in the proof of Stepanov's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation, lipschitz-functions

I am reading Maly's proof of Stepanov's theorem which asserts the following:

**Theorem**
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, and let $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a function. Then $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere on
$$L(f) : = \{x\in \Omega : \text{Lip}f(x) < \infty\},$$

where
$$\text{Lip}f(x): = \limsup_{y \to x} \frac{|f(y)- f(x)|}{|y-x|} .$$

(for example, see Theorem 3.4 in [Lectures on Lipschitz Analysis](http://www.math.jyu.fi/research/reports/rep100.pdf)).

*Proof*: We may assume that $m=1$. Let $\{B_1, B_2, \ldots\}$ be the countable collection of balls contained in $\Omega$ such that each $B_i$ has rational center and radius, and $f_{|{B_i}}$ is bounded. In particular this collection covers $L(f)$.
Define
$$u_i(x): = \inf \{u(x) : u \, \text{is $i$-Lipschitz with $u\geq f$ on $B_i$}\} $$
and
$$v_i(x): = \sup \{v(x) : u \, \text{is $i$-Lipschitz with $v\leq f$ on $B_i$}\}. $$
[...]

In the proof, we say that "Is it clear that $f$ is differentiable at every point $a$, where, for some $i$, both  $u_i$ and $v_i$ are differentiable with $v_i(a) = u_i(a)$" (see page 24).

I would like to verify this claim.

If the derivative of $u_i$ and $v_i$ at point $a$ are equal, it seems to be clear, but what about in case that they are not equal?

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are $u_i$ and $v_i$? What is $\operatorname{Lip} f(x)$?

Comment: @Unit I have edited, sorry for unclarity.

Comment: I think there is a typo in the lecture notes: $B_i$ is chosen so that Lip$(f)|_{B_i}$ is bounded, not $f|_{B_i}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\{e_j\}$ denote the standard basis vectors in ${\mathbb R}^n$.

Suppose that both  $u_i$ and $v_i$ are differentiable at $a \in B_i$, with $v_i(a) = u_i(a)$.

Let $\psi=u_i-v_i$, so that $\psi \ge 0$ on $B_i$.

If $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x_j}(a) >0$, then $\psi(a-\epsilon e_j)<0$ for small enough $\epsilon>0$, a contradiction. Similarly, if  $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x_j}(a) <0$, then considering $\psi(a+\epsilon e_j)$ for small   $\epsilon>0$ yields a contradiction. Thus
$$ 0=\nabla \psi=\nabla u_i-\nabla v_i \,.$$

Comment: (+1) you went through the trouble of reading the lecture notes and clarify matters.